# Is there a term for when a soloist plays a passage, followed by the tutti repeating it?

Tags: theory

I was listening to Weber's Turandot Overture. A flute (or piccolo?) plays a theme, and then the entire orchestra plays the same thing. Is there a name for this?

Comment: chanting, maybe? there is a word for it in other languages I know, but I can't translate it to english.

Comment: Copycat :-)  .   How about "call and response"

Comment: In call and response, the response is an answer to the call, not merely a repeat. (Call= Shave and a haircut, response= six bits)

Answer (score 3):

More common in a solo concerto, this is a “tutti repeat” or “orchestral repetition”, where the entire orchestra echos the statement of a melodic subject in the solo.

Answer (score 2):

No special term, beyond variations on the (perfectly clear) description you've already given.  'The theme is stated by solo flute, then repeated by full orchestra.'